# What ko.applyBindings() is doing in knockout.js?

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to **knockout.js**. I have seen all tutorials having **ko.applyBindings()**. Actually, what is this method doing?

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#activating-knockout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It searches for `data-bind`s and then does whatever the specified bindings are programmed to do. See the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html).